# How can I redirect to previous page of my guarded auth0 path in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, auth0

I am currently following this [auth0 guide](https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-react-user-authentication/#Protecting-Routes) to protect my routes. If a user enters my guarded path, it will correctly lead me to my auth0 universal login page. However, if for 'x' reason a user decides to click on the browser's back button, **it will return to the guarded path which will once again redirect me to the auth0 universal login page!** I would be creating a ProtectedRoute component similar to the tutorial:

```
<Route
    component={withAuthenticationRequired(component, {
      onRedirecting: () => <Loading />,
    })}
    {...args}
/>
```

Is there a way for me to redirect to the previous page before reaching the guarded path when I click on the browser's back button?

What I had in mind was to call a 'componentWillMount' function to check if the page was reached by calling the back button and then I would call *history.push('/')*;

```
const useWillMount = (fn) => {
    const willMount = useRef(true);

    if (willMount.current && fn && typeof fn === 'function') {
      fn();
    }

    willMount.current = false;
};

useWillMount(() => {
    if (
      String(window.performance.getEntriesByType('navigation')[0].type) ===
      'back_forward'
    ) {
      history.push('/');
    }
});
```

Using this, it correctly redirects to the home page. However, after a few milliseconds, it immediately throws me back to auth0 universal login page. (I believe this happens because it renders the ProtectedRoute component even though I called the history.push). Am I going towards the correct path, or am I completely lost here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm more experienced with Vue than React so I can't comment on exact implementation but would an approach like this be suitable:

1. Each time a non-logged in user navigates to a non-protected page, the path is stored as the `page` key in local storage
2. User navigates to protected route while not logged in.
3. If it does not exist, key called `route_guard_accessed` is stored in local storage and they are redirected to the login.
4. If user is redirected back to a protected page, and `route_guard_accessed` key exists in local storage, redirect them to the page stored in `path` key.
5. If user was redirected back to their old, non-protected page and `route_guard_accessed` key exists, then delete it from local storage.

In essence, you log the last non-protected page a non-logged-in user accesses. You also log when they attempt to access a protected page. If they access the protected page and they don't have the `route_guard_accessed` key in local storage, they are redirected to login. If they do, they are redirected back to their last non-protected page and the `route_guard_accessed` key is destroyed.